# JQuery Mobile: How to implement did select method to the Split view, to display corresponding selected row's information and details in details view

Tags: jquery, iphone, jquery-mobile, cordova, uisplitviewcontroller

I Have implemented **`Split view model`** in ***`Jquery mobile + phone gap`*** by following the instructions in the link:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qnNyHPWRz-Y .

Its very easy to implement a **split view for iPad** in **JQuery mobile**

and it takes 2-3 minuits to implement a **`split view using jQuery mobile+ phone gap in iPad`**.

```
 <body> 
        <div data-role="page" data-theme="e" data-content-theme="d">

            <div data-role="header">
                JQuery Split View using link http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qnNyHPWRz-Y
            </div>

            <div data-role="content">

                <!--- Right side view------>
                <div class="content-secondary">
                    <h3>Root View</h3>
                    <ul data-role="listview">
                        <li>Ashford Ridge Mine</li>
                        <li>Ashland Gold Mine</li>
                        <li>Brodford mine</li>
                        <li>Big Horn Mine</li>
                        <li>Elko pass</li>
                        <li>Emerad pine Gold</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <!--- Right side view------>
                <div class="content-primary">
                    <h3>Details View</h3>
                    <p>
                    Detail VIEWS goes here......            
                    </p>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </body>
```

I need ti implement did select method to the left side root view

as ***`when we click a row in left side table it to display corresponding selected row's information and details in right side details view.`***

![enter image description here][1]
But **`how to implement did select method to the left side root view`**

to ***`display corresponding selected row's information and details in right side details view in the form of table views.`***

Or ***`please provide me a good tutorial for Split view using jQuery mobile phone gap in iPhone`***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other way is to show and hide the div using css. There could also a better way to do it. by my 2cents!!

splitwin.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
    <title>Another Page</title>     
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.0.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jqm-docs.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/demo.js"></script>
</head> 
<body>

 <body>
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="e" data-content-theme="d">
        <div data-role="header">
            JQuery Split View using link http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qnNyHPWRz-Y
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <!--- Right side view------>
            <div class="content-secondary">
                <h3>Root View</h3>
                <ul data-role="listview">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" id="Ashford">Ashford Ridge Mine</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" id="Ashland">Ashland Gold Mine</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Brodford mine
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Big Horn Mine
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Elko pass
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Emerad pine Gold
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!--- Right side view------>
            <div class="content-primary">
                <h3>Details View</h3>
                <p>
                    Detail VIEWS goes here......
                    <div id="link1" style="display:none">
                        Clicked 
                        Ashford Ridge Mine
                    </div>
                        <div id="link2" style="display:none">
                        Clicked 
                        Ashland Gold Mine
                    </div>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        </body> 

</body>
</html>
```

demo.js

```
$('a#Ashford').live('click', function() {
    $("div#link2").hide();  
    $("div#link1").show();  
});

$('a#Ashland').live('click', function() {
    $("div#link1").hide();  
    $("div#link2").show();  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this...

```
$('ul[data-role="listview"] li').click(function() {
    var li_text = $(this).text();
    $.ajax({
       url:'<url to get detail from li text>',
       data : 'data='+li_text,
       success: function(result) {
           $('.content-primary').find('p').get(0).html(result);
       } // <-- add this
    });
});
```